# Can a large error be calculated using logarithm?

Tags: logarithms, error-function, standard-error

For example:
$$\begin{array}{l}
y = {x^{11}}\\
\Delta x = 0.1 \cdot x\\
\Delta y =\sqrt {\left( {\frac{{dy}}{{dx}}\Delta x} \right)^2} = 1.1 \cdot {x^{10}}\\
y \pm \Delta y = {x^{10}} \pm 1.1 \cdot {x^{10}}\\
\pm \frac{{\Delta y}}{y} =  \pm 110\% 
\end{array}$$

This above looks incorrect because more than 100%.

But the next
$$\begin{array}{l}
y = {x^{11}}\\
\Delta x = 0.1 \cdot x\\
x \pm \Delta x = \left( {1 \pm 0.1} \right) \cdot x \approx x \cdot {e^{ \pm 0.1}}\\
y \pm \Delta y = \left( {1 \pm {\delta _y}} \right) \cdot y \approx y \cdot {e^{ \pm {\delta _y}}} = {e^{\ln y \pm {\delta _y}}}\\
{\delta _y} = \frac{{d\ln y}}{{dx}}\Delta x = 1.1\\
y \pm \Delta y \approx y \cdot {e^{ \pm {\delta _y}}} = y \cdot {e^{ \pm 1.1}} = {x^{11}} \cdot {e^{ \pm 1.1}} = {\left( {x \cdot {e^{ \pm 0.1}}} \right)^{11}} \approx {\left( {\left( {1 \pm 0.1} \right) \cdot x} \right)^{11}}\\
\pm \frac{{\Delta y}}{y} ={e^{ \pm 1.1}} = \left[ \begin{array}{l}
 + 200\% \\
 - 67\% 
\end{array} \right.
\end{array}$$
looks acceptable.

Is there a proper name for such a method of error calculation? Or is such an approach unacceptable using logarithm?

Comment: What? Nothing in your example makes any sense- why is there a square of the derivative? What’s $f$? In another you have $y$ is $x^{10}$. Your equations don’t line up with each from one line to the next.

Comment: Thanks for indicating errors in letters.

Comment: Both methods are approximate. The logarithmic approximation works better in this particular case. If you set $\Delta x = 0.9x$ then neither method works well, although the logarithmic method at least says the result will be positive.

Comment: Now consider $\Delta x=2x$. The logarithmic approach will still say that the change in the function value in the negative direction is less than $100\%$ even though it is most definitely greater than $100\%$. The truth is that all estimation methods of this sort only work if $\Delta x$ is small enough.